# Find multiple values, concatenate cooresponding values in other column, write to cell

Tags: loops, excel, for-loop, vba

Problem:

Nothing  is being written into cells in column P. The line Cells(x, "P").Value = failingClasses should do this.

Description: (VBA script below)

I've got a column with ID numbers. There can be multiple rows with each ID number. What I need to do is concatenate all the corresponding values in another column and write this into a cell in the original row. This needs to be done for each row in the sheet.

Field 1 is where the IDs are, field 6 is where the information I want to concatenate is, I'm trying to write the concatenation into column P.

Right now, I think that the computation is being done correctly, but for what ever reason it isn't writing to the cell in P?

Macro takes *for ever* to run. Between 1k and 2k rows when run.

Thanks!

```
Worksheets("RAW GRADE DATA").Select
    ' Turn off auto calc update and screen update -- saves speed

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Dim x As Long, y As Long, totalGradeEntries As Long, failingClasses As String, failingClassesCell As Excel.Range

    totalGradeEntries = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = totalGradeEntries To 1 Step -1

        failingClasses = ""

        For y = totalGradeEntries To 1 Step -1

            If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value And Cells(x, 6) <> "02HR" Then
                failingClasses = failingClasses & " " & Cells(y, 1).Value
            End If

            Cells(x, "P").Value = failingClasses
        Next y
    Next x

    ' Turn calc and screen update back on

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: The double loop is what's killing the speed.  Are the ID's always consecutive (sorted) or are they unordered?  (i.e. unordered 123,155,123,143... 123 is separated by other ID's)

Comment: 1. Put a breakpoint on the Cells(x,"P").Value = line and see what is in failingClasses at that time.  2. Only write to Cells(x,"P") once -- now you are writing with every inner loop.  3. To increase speed considerably, do the "work" in a VBA array, rather than on the worksheet.

Comment: Portland Runner -- I know that the double loop is killing the speed. The IDs are unordered, but I could just do a sort before the loop runs to fix that. There is a maximum of 9 entries per ID. Could this help speed it up?

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld -- The reason I am writing to every row is because I need to later use a subset of these (yet another column, that for every ID has a value that shows up only once.) However, I need the data from all the rows concatenated first. Can you explain how to do the "work" in an array a little? I know some python and R, and know how I could do this in those very easily, but I don't know VBA as well, and this has to be done in Excel. Thanks!

Comment: You can write to every row, but you only need to write once, not once for every total grade entries as you are doing now.  For arrays, declare a variable of type variant, then a statement like  Var = RangeToProcess will read the entire range into a 2D array in one step.  (D1=rows; D2=columns).  Then iterate through to process your data.  When done:  Range = Var will output it back to the worksheet.  In my experience, a ten-fold speed increase is common.

Comment: Well your code is working for me although I think the line failingClasses = failingClasses & " " & Cells(y, 1).Value should be failingClasses = failingClasses & " " & Cells(y, 6).Value otherwise  it concatenates the Id col A.  Also what is the significance of "02HR" and where does this feature in col 6?  PS I did put the Ids in order.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld -- Thanks, I will look into it. I'm familiar with arrays from R, t don't know the syntax in VBA.

Comment: Barrwajo -- hrm. Is it actually writing to the cell? Thanks fur catching the other error. Ill update the question when I'm back on a machine.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld -- Thanks for the response. That should be enough to get me rolling, and sounds much more sensible than writing through the entire range cell by cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the bones of a solution to this work, thanks to Ron Rosenfeld -- Here is the code, working on a test sheet with 3 columns of data, the Unique IDs being in column 1.

```
Sub CalcArrary()

    'Declare variables
    Dim numRows As Integer, calcArray() As Variant

    'Set the number of rows in the sheet
    numRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(Sheet1.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim calcArray(numRows - 1, 4)

    For i = 0 To numRows - 2
        calcArray(i, 1) = Range("A" & i + 2)
        calcArray(i, 2) = Range("B" & i + 2)
        calcArray(i, 3) = Range("C" & i + 2)
    Next i

    For b = 0 To numRows - 2

        For c = 0 To numRows - 2

            If calcArray(c, 1) = calcArray(b, 1) And calcArray(c, 3) < 60 Then

                calcArray(b, 4) = calcArray(b, 4) & calcArray(c, 2) & ", " & calcArray(c, 3) & "%      "

            End If

        Next c
    Next b

    For d = 0 To numRows - 2

        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & d + 2) = calcArray(d, 4)

    Next d

End Sub
```

Comment: Just ran the live version on my actual data --- Ron Rosenfeld, thank you SO much. From 60 minutes execution to ~ 6 seconds. Literally.